# SKSpriteNode created from SKTexture(data:size:) issues with Alpha (Opacity)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, rgba, sktexture

I'm having a problem when creating an SKSpriteNode from pixelData.

Below is my code.

```
var pixelData: [UInt32] = [UInt32](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0xff0000ff)
pixelData.appendContentsOf([UInt32](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0xff00ff00))
pixelData.appendContentsOf([UInt32](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0xffff0000))
pixelData.appendContentsOf([UInt32](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0x000000ff))

let data = NSData(bytes: pixelData, length: pixelData.count * sizeof(UInt32))

let texture = SKTexture(data: data, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))

let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))
node.position.x = self.frame.midX
node.position.y = self.frame.midY

self.addChild(node)
```

It went as I wish for the three bottom rows (which is the first 3 parts in the pixelData array, `0xff0000ff`, `0xff00ff00`, `0xffff0000`: Red, Green, and Blue).

However, I expected the top row to be totally transparent: `0x000000ff`, which should mean rgba(1, 0, 0, 0). But it appeared as this:

[image]

I don't know why this happen. Is my understanding of pixelData wrong? Or is it a bug or something in SpriteKit?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the convenience method to convert pixel data to an `SKTexture`,

> The color components should have been already multiplied by the alpha value.

Consequently, the value `0x000000ff` is undefined, since the red component cannot be `0xff` if the alpha value is 0. Also, it is somewhat non-intuitive to represent a pixel color with a hexadecimal value particularly when the components are in reversed order.

Alternatively, you can define a data structure to represent a color and then pre-multiply each color component by the alpha value during initialization:

```
struct Color {
    var red:UInt8
    var green:UInt8
    var blue:UInt8
    var alpha:UInt8

    // You can omit the parameters that have default values.
    init(red:UInt8=0, green:UInt8=0, blue:UInt8=0, alpha:UInt8=UInt8.max) {
        let alphaValue:Float = Float(alpha) / 255
        self.red = UInt8(round(Float(red) * alphaValue))
        self.green = UInt8(round(Float(blue) * alphaValue))
        self.blue = UInt8(round(Float(green) * alphaValue))
        self.alpha = alpha
    }
}
```

You can then define and initialize a `pixelData` array with the "same" values as your code by

```
    var pixelData:[Color] = [Color](count: 256, repeatedValue: Color(red: UInt8.max))
    pixelData += [Color](count:256, repeatedValue: Color(green: UInt8.max))
    pixelData += [Color](count:256, repeatedValue: Color(blue: UInt8.max))
    pixelData += [Color](count:256, repeatedValue: Color(red: UInt8.max, alpha: 0))
```

and create the `NSData` object with

```
    let data = NSData(bytes: pixelData, length: pixelData.count * sizeof(Color))
```